# error performing a get request

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to perform a `get` request, in the `post` request everything is OK, I can see that in the `post` request all I do it's been save, once I refresh the page I am printing in the console the items saved by the post request, but those items aren't been return with the `get` I am doing.

here is where everything begins, I have a list of items here with the option to checked or unchecked the items in the list

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="sport in sports" ng-click="toggleSportSelection(sport)">
    {{:: sport.name}}
</ion-item>
```

all the items are `checked = true` by default, so what I am saving, are the items with `checked = false`, the items `checked = true` you can see them here

```
<div ng-show="sport.checked" ng-repeat="sport in sports">
     {{sport.name}}
</div>
```

this is what I have in the controller

```
.controller('SportsController', function($scope, SportsFactory) {

 SportsFactory.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
        _.each(sports, function(sport) {
          var sportIds = _.pluck(sport, 'id'),
              intersectedSports = _.intersection(sport.id, sportChecked),
              checkedSportObjects = _.filter(sport, function(sportObj) {
                return _.includes(intersectedSports, sportObj);
              });
          _.each(checkedSportObjects, function(sport) {
            $scope.sports.push(sport);
          });
        });
      }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });


    $scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) {
      var params = {};
      params.user = $scope.customer.customer;
      params.sport = sport.id;
      sport.checked = !sport.checked;
      SportsFactory.setSportChecked(params);
    };
   // this is what puts the sports on checked = true
   if (sports.length) {
        $scope.sports = _.map(sports, function(sport) {
          sport.checked = true;
          return sport;
        });
      }
```

and this is the service / factory

```
 .factory('SportsFactory', function($http, $q, AuthFactory,
                                    LocalForageFactory, CONSTANT_VARS) {
    return {

  getSportChecked: function(customer) {
    var defer = $q.defer(),
        user,
        rejection = function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          defer.reject(err);
        };
    LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED)
      .then(function(sportChecked) {
        user = customer.customer;
        if (!_.isNull(sportChecked)) {
          defer.resolve(sportChecked);
        }else {
          $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/getChecked/' + user)
          .success(function(sportChecked) {
            LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED, sportChecked);
            defer.resolve(sportChecked);
          })
          .error(rejection);
        }
      }, rejection);
    return defer.promise;
  }
});
```

I am working along with NodeJS, so if you want the code I have in that part just let me know, so far I think that the issue I have is in the front end part, in the controller.

Comment: What is the error that's being thrown by your code?

Comment: @freshnode I am not getting errors, is just that once I refresh, I lost the checked and unchecked elements

Comment: try to initialize: $scope.sports = [] before the _.each on get callback